# React styled component as a property TypeScript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Consider the following example:

```
const StyledComponent = styled.div` ... `;

interface ComponentProps {
  styledComponent: any;
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = () => { ... };

Component.styledComponent = StyledComponent;

export default Component;
```

I use this to reference component's styled component in other components. Works as expected, however I keep TypeScript complaining:

```
Property 'styledComponent' does not exist on type 'FC<ComponentProps>'.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define component:

```
const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> & { styledComponent: any } = () => { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected. Mind to provide more information about what this code does?

Comment: I don't know what more add :)

Comment: When you use `React.FC<SomeType>` it just types the function to accept the `props` argument of `SomeType`. What you wanted is to have the function itself to conform to `SomeType`. And the constuct in the answer allows for that.

Comment: Want to take this opportunity to ask the correct type for a styled component? Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @tromgy Thx for help me for this answer !

Comment: @sdvnksv I can provide how use styled components with ts: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-darwin-ehrzj?file=/src/App.tsx